# Access & Encrypt pem file using Shell Script

Tags: ios, xcode, bash, encryption, cryptography

I have added .p12 & .pem file into the project.

Now, I want to encrypt this pem file using .p12 build time using shell script in Xcode.

How can we access these files & encrypt it?

I know the encrypt command like:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in path.p12 -out encrypted.key.pem -nocerts -nodes
```

So,  this is like one key to encrypt another key, if I am not wrong.

Comment: Is this related to your previous questions?  It still isn't clear what you are hoping to achieve. Embedding a key in your app isn't secure.

Comment: yes, @Paulw11, we have changed some logic now. Eventhough we embed key into app, we are removed the file from "copy bundle resource", so client think it is secure now if we don't copy it.

Comment: @Paulw11, I am creating POC now to prove wrong client, I need to create shell script which encrypt the embedded PEM file using p12 file 
Please let me know if you know how to write shell script for this

Comment: But if the key isn't in the bundle, how will the app make use of it? But p12 and pem are just file formats. What do you have in those files. Keys, certifcates?  What sort of keys?

Comment: @Paulw11, both file have keys only.

Comment: The command you have shown will convert a key in an p12 file to a PEM format but it won't encrypt anything. `-nodes` means "don't encrypt private keys".  If you omit that argument then the default triple DES encryption will be applied to the private key that is written to the PEM file.